# Is there a way to get "out-evcent" in igraph?

Tags: igraph, eigenvector

So I browsed the site and saw that evcent() returns the "in-evcent" for weighted, directed networks. Is there any way to compute the out-evcent with igraph or would I need a different package for that?

The value for being well connected to vertices with alot of indegree is not useful for my research. I kinda need the value of being of being well connected  to vertices that have strong weighted outdegree.

Comment: Reverse the edges, and then you'll get out-evcent.

Comment: Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: Something like this: `graph.edgelist(get.edgelist(g, names = FALSE)[,2:1])`

Comment: well that did nothing but I just mirrored my excel table due to lack of r skill on my part and that worked, thanks for your input though.

Comment: Well, if it did nothing, then you did it wrong. :)